# Django - unable to publish Linux server

Tags: python, django, linux, port, portforwarding

First of all, I can access the webpage from local host. But if I were to access it from outside machines, I am unable to access the page.

This is what I get when I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 18, 2018 - 05:45:59
Django version 2.0.6, using settings 'sage.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.1.2 development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-09-18 05:45:59,176 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2018-09-18 05:45:59,179 - INFO - server - Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0
2018-09-18 05:45:59,180 - INFO - server - Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Lets assume that my IP address for my Linux server is `70.111.222.333`. Then I should be able to access it from other computers by typing `http://70.111.222.333:8000` on a browser. But it doesn't work.

In my `settings.py`, this is how it looks right now:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['', '*']
```

The Linux server has a few virtual machines installed, and I've correctly set up fort forwarding for my application virtual machine, `port 8000`, `Local IP 192.168.1.100`. And yet, I am still unable to publish my Linux server. It says that the site can't be reached.

Any idea how to fix this?

I'm using Django-Channels, FYI

Comment: If you are not seeing anything on the console it may mean that you haven't set up port forwarding correctly contrary to what you think.

Comment: Can you connect to the process locally?  telnet localhost 8000  There's so much that can be going wrong. The next thing to check is firewalling; use tcpdump on the server if the process accepts local network connections to see whether there's any connectivity at all ... can you ping the machine it's hosted on from your workstation?

Comment: @tink I am able to ssh to the server through port 3333, which I set up on router port forwarding page.

Comment: May I suggest you show (sanitised) firewall rules of both the server and the vm in your post above, and explain how you did the forwarding? Just edit it (mark it as such).

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should use a python gateway server interface [like gunicorn or uwsgi](https://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn) to serve your app in production. Don't use the `./manage.py runserver` command.

Second, if you run an app in production (that means `DEBUG=False`), you need to serve static resources on your own, which means you need a webserver (like nginx or apache2).

As soon as you set up a webserver to serve your static resources, create a proxy to the Django app.

For Apache:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

Also set the preserve host header to use the hostname of your virtual host.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

Here is a complete example of a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.ch
    ServerAlias www.example.ch

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</VirtualHost>
```